# How can I hide or show Navbar?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, jsx

**Goal**: I need to when user is not null then show Navbar for this I use useEffect and useState. How did I understand when the site is loaded user is no longer null so useEffect does not work. How do I make it work?

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth } from "./components/LoginForm/firebase.js";

function App() {
  const user = auth.currentUser

  const [Navbarshow, setNavbar] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user === null) {
      setNavbar(true)
    }
  }, [user])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        {Navbarshow ? <Navbar /> : null}
        <button onClick={() => console.log(Navbarshow, user)}>Test</button>
```

> This is a part of App.js, where is problem

Comment: What is `auth` and `auth.currentUser`? It doesn't seem like this value changing will trigger this `App` component to rerender to pick up the change. Can you edit your post to include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try this I hope this works. thanks

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (!auth.currentUser) {
     setNavbar(true)
   } else {
     setNavbar(false)
   }
}, [auth.currentUser])
```

Comment: It works But when I sign out it shows Navbar how can I set to false?

Comment: I have updated the code, your auth.currentUser should be null when you sign out. please check the above code.

Comment: If I am not loggined it gives false and auth.currentUser is null and then it gives true and auth.currentUser is null

Comment: then I hope this code works. :)

Comment: It gives same result (

Comment: Would you please try log `auth.currentUser` value when signing out, whether the `auth.currentUser` value will be empty or not and add it to the log in`useEffect`, when you signout, whether 'useEffect' is calling or not.